# Does a fundamental principle require specific concepts?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, soft-question, angular-momentum, conservation-laws

The angular momentum principle is a fundamental principle. So it can explain a large variety of phenomenon. Doesn't it need concepts like center of mass also for explaining phenomenon? Or just the angular momentum principle can explain these phenomenon?

Comment: What i am asking is,when we say a very few fundamental principles can explain a broad range of phenomenon,are we meaning 'fundamental principles and some related concepts'?

Comment: Hi Krishlovesphysics. Welcome to Phys.SE. Minor comments to the question (v2): (i) Please provide an informative title other than just saying _Fundamentals of physics._ (ii) Don't use comments to improve the question. Edit the question instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even fundamental principles require a framework in which they hold. The conservation of angular momentum for example requires the concepts of space, time and mass. Before you can speak of angular momentum (and its conservation), you need to define what it refers to. In this case, it would be the rotational motion of some body around a certain axis. You have to be able to speak about motion (change in time), position (spatial properties) and fundamental properties of the moving object (mass).

That there exist fundamental principles (like conservation laws in classical mechanics, gauge invariance in particle physics, ...) does not mean there is nothing else to physics. It just means that these principles stand at the core of the physical description of our universe, and that their impact on the phenomena we observe is of great importance.

Comment: Oh...these concepts stand at the core and other concepts are connected to them.like the concepts of space,mass,time,center of mass and torque are connected to angular momentum principle..right?

Comment: That is correct. However, what qualifies as "at the core" might be a matter of definition. What I mean are principles that occur everywhere in physics and dominate observed phenomena in a drastic way.

Comment: So even when we are saying fundamentals explain everything,we do it with the help of other concepts attached to it..right?

Comment: Yes, you are right.